# "Assembly name or codebase was invalid" trying to add new data source

Tags: winforms, datasource

Here's a problem which is driving us nuts. We have an old VB2005 application which only needs a new RDLC report adding.

However to add the RDLC we need to add a new data source. Every time we try to add a new datasource using the **Object** option (not dataset) we get this error:

[image]

Now, you can get some help on Google for this but a lot of it is for web projects. This is a Winforms project.

Here's what we've tried:

- devenv.exe /ResetSettings
- checking the Assembly name doesn't have any punctuation or weird characters in it (this is a favourite solution from Google) - it doesn't
- removing the source control (Perforce)
- rebuilding the project from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our solution was to upgrade the project to VS2008. Didn't really want to as we feared destabilising the application in unpredictable ways just to achieve an edit in a report.

But in fact the upgrade *did* solve the data source problem, and so far at least, there haven't been any side effects.